# How to navigate to view from list-item level?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I develop Vue2 app using Vuetify. I use `router-view` to navigate to views. I created navigation drawer where I added groups and subgroups. I created separate views for each subgroup eg. `AFRrev.vue` for subgroup `Revenues`, `AFRstats.vue` for subgroup `Stats`, same for SFR, CLC etc.. What I want to do is to navigate to specific view when selecting a subgroup. I added picture to show how it looks like now:

[image]

The issue is that I need to add route to attribute `:to` in `v-list-item` (in subgroup) which refers to the name of the group - and then I will able to create a path string eg. `route: this.allGroupItems.text + 'rev'` should give `AFRrev` route to `AFRrev.vue` view. As you can see I try to retrieve name of the route through `allGroupItems.text` but it doesn't work. And yes, I defined all routes correctly in vue router.

Here are examples of my views:

**AFRrev.vue**

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        Some data
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>
```

**AFRstats.vue**

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        Some edata
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>
```

Here is main code:

**Drawer.vue**

```
<template>
    <v-navigation-drawer app width="215">

    <v-list>

      <v-list-group
        v-for="item in allGroupItems"
        :key="item.id">
          <template v-slot:activator>
            <v-list-item-title >
              {{ item.text }}
            </v-list-item-title>
          </template>

          <v-list-item
            v-for="item in allSubgroupItems"
            :key="item.id"
            :to="item.route"
            link>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title> {{ item.text }}</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>          
      </v-list-group>
    </v-list>
    <v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
    data () {
      return {
        allGroupItems: [
          { id: 1,  text: "AFR"},
          { id: 2,  text: "SFR"},
          { id: 3,  text: "CBR"},
          { id: 4,  text: "CLC"}
        ],
        allSubgroupItems: [
          { id: 1.1,  text: "Revenues", route: this.allGroupItems.text + 'rev' },
          { id: 2.1, text: "Stats", route: this.allGroupItems.text + 'stats'  }
        ],
  }
},
}
</script>
```

How can I refer to group name as to create a route path?
Maybe I should refer to component name somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<v-list-item>` is nested inside `<v-list-group>` and therefore you should be able to access the `item` from `<v-list-group>` inside `<v-list-item>`, which would enable you to construct your route properly in the template.

The reason you can't do that is because when you iterate in `<v-list-item>`, you use the name `item` again which overrides the `item` variable from `<v-list-group>`.

If you rename the `item` variables to something more descriptive in `<v-list-group>` and `<v-list-item>`, you should be able to do something like the following:

```
 <v-list-group
        v-for="groupItem in allGroupItems"
        :key="groupItem.id">
          <template v-slot:activator>
            <v-list-item-title >
              {{ groupItem.text }}
            </v-list-item-title>
          </template>

          <v-list-item
            v-for="subItem in allSubgroupItems"
            :key="subItem.id"
            :to="groupItem.text + subItem.route"
            link>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title> {{ subItem.text }}</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>          
      </v-list-group>
```